# Why are my JButtons not responding when clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to use the `actionPerformed` method to print a message to the corresponding buttons (in this case `b1`/`b2`/`b3`). I have no idea where exactly in the code the issue lies.

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class B_HangMan implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;
    JButton b3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setSize(900, 500);
        frame1.setLocation(500, 200);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);

        // button 1
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        b1.setBounds(20, 20, 90, 90);
        b1.addActionListener(new B_HangMan());
        mainPanel.add(b1);

        // button 2
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        b2.setBounds(130, 20, 90, 90);
        b2.addActionListener(new B_HangMan());
        mainPanel.add(b2);

        // button 3
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        b3.setBounds(240, 20, 90, 90);
        b3.addActionListener(new B_HangMan());
        mainPanel.add(b3);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            System.out.println("button 1 was clicked");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            System.out.println("button 2 was clicked");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b3) {
            System.out.println("button 3 was clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

The console should display which one was pressed when clicking on the different buttons. Nothing happens instead.

Comment: I suspect that they are, but you've shadowed your instance variables with local ones (ie `b1` is declared twice).  Instance of using the object instance, perhaps you should consider making use of the `actionCommand` support

Comment: in addition to the comment by @MadProgrammer: you are using different instances of hangman for each button

Answer (score 1):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75037974/why-are-my-jbuttons-not-responding-when-clicked#comment132419504_75037974), by @MadProgrammer, is telling you why nothing happens when you click on any of the [buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), namely that your code contains [shadowing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shadowing-in-java/) (not to be confused with [hiding](https://www.scaler.com/topics/java/variable-hiding-and-variable-shadowing-in-java/)). In other words, you have local variables with the same declaration as [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

I don't know how you are learning *Swing* but it is a vast API and the quintessential tutorial is this one:

> [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

There are also several books devoted entirely to *Swing*.

```java
mainPanel.setLayout(null);
```

You usually don't need to use a null layout. I believe that [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) is appropriate for displaying your buttons.

Also, since Java 8, you can implement [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Here is my rewrite of your code which aims to show you several other features of *Swing*, apart from fixing your problem whereby clicking on any of the buttons does nothing.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HangmanB {

    private void buildAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        URL url = getClass().getResource("hangman16.png");
        try {
            Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
            frame.setIconImage(img);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, ActionListener listener) {
        JButton b = new JButton(text);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 90));
        b.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        return b;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 20, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 8, 0, 0));
        panel.add(createButton("1", KeyEvent.VK_1, this::handleButton1));
        panel.add(createButton("2", KeyEvent.VK_2, this::handleButton2));
        panel.add(createButton("3", KeyEvent.VK_3, this::handleButton3));
        return panel;
    }

    private void handleButton1(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("button 1 was clicked");
    }

    private void handleButton2(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("button 2 was clicked");
    }

    private void handleButton3(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("button 3 was clicked");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new HangmanB().buildAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the GUI when I run the above code:

[image: screen capture]